# How to stop nginx process, even after uninstall this web server?

Tags: nginx, debian

In my debian PC i had a nginx server, but i removed it completely. Now i have permanently :80 port busy.
I ran any kind of command for stop those services, but they execute again. 
What can i do for set free 80 port? THX.

```
nginx      6593            root    6u  IPv4 345904      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      6605 systemd-network    6u  IPv4 345904      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: have you kill the process by pid ?

Comment: Yes. I have. Then the process appear automatically with another ID.

Comment: [SOLVED] I found another nginx docker container running in this PC. I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply `kill` the process.
kill command syntax

```
# kill [signal or option] PID(s)
```

So in your case,

```
kill SIGTERM 6593
```

You might need to be as root, so prepend with `sudo` as appropriate

Answer (score 0):

for Linux:

```
fuser -k 80/tcp
```

or,

```
kill $(lsof -t -i:80)
```